# Python, MySQL deadlocks on transaction

Tags: python, mysql, deadlock

I am having a huge table that bothers me. I have more that 350 millions records in this table and it grows every seconds. I am trying to do statistics on this table to build static reports. The problem is that I am getting a lot of deadlocks. The logic of the reports is implemented in python and makes MySQL queries. I am trying to find a mechanism or a way to tell to my python code to always retry the query if it detects a deadlocks. The thing is that it deadlocks even if I am using the dirty records.

I which I could do something like:

```
retry until completion:
  query('SELECT ....')
```

Regards
Dominick

Comment: If you have a table like that, you really should not be doing statistical reporting on the production database.  You really should be using a replicated setup and doing your statistics on the replica so as to not interfere with your database.  Of course you also need to make sure you are running queries on indexed fields.

Comment: We do insert in table A and every 5 minutes we move records from table A to table B with exact same schema. Stats are compiled from table B that is at the end only the final storage where the data lives. Table B is a monthly table so I know at the end of the month no more inserts will be done on this table.

Comment: I think that Mike Brant was talking about the risk that, if you write a buggy request, or even if you just highly increase the load average, you can freeze/destroy/corrupt all the production database. Which is probably not what you want...

Comment: Ah no worries there it is a MySQL slave. But it still gets the replication from the master.